# How to return Any from a function?

Tags: rust, typing

I am working on type system for a database project. One problem is mapping a type id to a reader that given an type id and address, a function can return given any data type from built in `u32`, `String`, to defined structs.

I don't have any problem on writers, like such macro

```
    fn set_val (data: &Any, id:i32, mem_ptr: usize) {
         match id {
             $(
                 $id => $io::write(*data.downcast_ref::<$t>().unwrap(), mem_ptr),
             )*
             _ => (),
         }
    }
```

But for the reader `Any` seems not comfortable to be used as return value because the `the trait bound "std::any::Any + 'static: std::marker::Sized" is not satisfied`. I also tried to return as a reference, but I am stuck at a lifetime

```
    fn get_val (id:i32, mem_ptr: usize) -> Option<& Any> {
         match id {
             $(
                 $id => Some(&$io::read(mem_ptr)),
             )*
             _ => None,
         }
    }
```

which complains `missing lifetime specifier`. If `'static` won't work here due to the return value not live long enough, how can I specify the lifetime here?

PS. The read function from $io returns any kinds of types.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`Any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html) is a trait, which means that it is unsized and thus cannot be returned by a function as is.

However, you can try boxing it:

```
fn get_val (id:i32, mem_ptr: usize) -> Option<Box<Any>> {
     match id {
         $(
             $id => Some(Box::new($io::read(mem_ptr))),
         )*
         _ => None,
     }
}
```

An example [playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=use%20std%3A%3Aany%3A%3AAny%3B%0A%0Astatic%20DATA%3A%20%5Bu8%3B%202%5D%20%3D%20%5B1%2C%202%5D%3B%0A%0Afn%20fun(numbers%3A%20bool)%20-%3E%20Box%3CAny%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20numbers%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Box%3A%3Anew(%26DATA)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Box%3A%3Anew(String%3A%3Afrom(%22Heya!%22))%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20smth%20%3D%20fun(true)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20smth.downcast_ref%3A%3A%3C%26%5Bu8%3B%202%5D%3E())%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20smth%20%3D%20fun(false)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20smth.downcast_ref%3A%3A%3CString%3E())%3B%0A%7D&version=stable&backtrace=0).